# Is there web front-end of Swift written in Python？

Tags: openstack, openstack-swift

ownCloud is a solution, but it is written in PHP and too huge.
Is there any other open source project written in Python.
Or I want to write a web front-end for swift based on Python Django, is this a good idea?
Thanks！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honghe.Wu

The OpenStack Dashboard is written in Python and its a web front end which gives Swift as well. I am sure if you will dig the code you will get a good idea about it and then you can write for your own using python https://github.com/openstack/horizon

Hope it helps, also do let me know if your planning to release the dashboard under open source, i won`t mind testing it for you. :)

Good luck!!

Comment: Will notice you if have some progress. Thx!